# Best way to accumulate futures

Tags: scala, akka

Say I have a function that returns a Future and depending on the result of this function I may need to call it again or I may return immediately. And I need to accumulate these results in a list. I want to define a function that returns this list as a Future. I have got the following:

```
def foo: Future[Int] { ... }

def accum(i: Future[Int], l: List[Int]): Future[List[Int]] = i.map { i =>
    if (i >= max)
        l
    else 
        accum(foo, i :: l)
}

def test: Future[List[Int]] = accum(foo, List())
```

But of course this won't compile because the call to accum() within the map needs to return a List[Int] rather than a Future[List[Int]]. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always return a `Future` from the inner block, and use `flatMap`:

```
def accum(i: Future[Int], l: List[Int]): Future[List[Int]] =
  i.flatMap { i =>
    if (i >= max)
      Future.successful(l)
    else 
      accum(foo, i :: l)
  }
```

Depending on where `foo` comes from you might also want to consider e.g. scalaz's `foldLeftM` rather than an explicit recursive function.

Answer (score 0):

I think following will work for you,

```
def foo: Future[Int] = ???

def accumulate( max: Int, f: () => Future[ Int ], list: List[ Int ] = List[ Int ]() ): Future[ List[ Int ] ] = {
  val intFuture = f()

  intFuture.flatMap( ( i: Int ) => {
    // if future is successfull
    if ( i < max ) {
      // If value less than max, keep on accumulating more 
      accumulate( max, f, list :+ i )
    }
    else {
      // If value not less than max, stop accumulating more
      // Just wrap the list in future and return
      val promiseOfList = Promise[ List[ Int ] ]()
      promiseOfList.complete( Success( list ) )
      promiseOfList.future
    }
  } ).fallbackTo( {
    // If this computation fails.... stop accumulating
    // Just wrap the list in future and return
    val promiseOfList = Promise[ List[ Int ] ]()
    promiseOfList.complete( Success( list ) )
    promiseOfList.future
  } )

}

val myListFuture = accumulate( max, foo )
```